# Find the indefinite integral:

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I have to find the indefinite integral of (e^x)(cos x).
I tried using integration by parts but I keep getting the same integral over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct that you get the integral again after two steps of integration by parts: 
$$
\int e^x \cos x dx =  e^x \cos x + \int e^x \sin x dx 
=e^x \cos x +  e^x \sin x - \int e^x \cos x dx 
$$
But note the opposite sign! Now move the integral to the LHS and get 
$$
\int e^x \cos x dx = \frac{1}{2}\left( e^x \cos x + e^x \sin x\right)
$$